# Unable to change UI of MDCTextField i

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, material-components-ios

I am trying to use the **MDCTextField** with **MDCTextInputControllerOutlined** of **MaterialComponents** in my swift project but I facing a major challenge with design adjustments in it. It's not allowing me to change even the height of the textfield as well to centre the text input part. Not even the fonts of placeholder is changing.
Tried following all possible options provided in sdk.

```
        tptf.placeholder = "Name"
        tptf.placeholderLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
        tptf.placeholderLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TimesNewRoman", size: 14)
        tptf.textColor = UIColor.green
        tptf.font = UIFont(name: "TimesNewRoman", size: 14)
        tptf.clearButtonMode = .unlessEditing
        tptf.delegate = self
        
        self.textController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: tptf)
        self.textController.textInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10))
        self.textController.activeColor = UIColor.green
        self.textController.floatingPlaceholderActiveColor = UIColor.green
```

PFA image[image]

Comment: have you found any solution to achieve this?

Comment: yes I implemented a custom textbook on my own.